# Cannot read cookie values

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am using the jquery.cookie.js plugin to create a cookie on a button click event. However, although the cookie is being set from the click, when i attempt to read the cookie i get error of: `TypeError: document.cookie.split is not a function`. I have searched google but cannot find answer for this error.

Also, no alert is being fired to show the cookie details. I have made sure that the js file is included directly after the jquery file. I would be grateful if someone could point out my where I am going wrong. Many thanks

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#accept", function(e) {
        $('#hideTabs').hide();
        $('#acceptMsg').fadeIn(2000).delay(2500).fadeOut(2500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#inline_content').popup('hide');
        }, 7000);
        var visited = $.cookie("visited");
        if (visited == null) {
            alert($.cookie("visited"));
        }
        // set cookie
        $.cookie('visited', 'yes', {
            secure: false,
            path: '/'
        });
        $.cookie();
    });
});
```

Comment: you use a outdated plugin see the new version at https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: @madalinivascu I have updated plugin to v2.2 and I am now getting an error of: `TypeError: $.cookie is not a function` Thanks

Comment: have a look at the documentation first you need Cookie.get/set

Comment: @madalinivascu I am using `Cookies.set('visited', 'yes');Cookies.get();` which is from the docs and I am still getting the split error. thanks

Comment: can you replicate this behavior in a jsfiddle?